# Pyspark: Try lambda function with if else statement if there's a null value returned

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following code:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], mapIds.get(x[1]), x[2])).toDF()
```

Where `mapIds` is a Python dictionary which maps each value of the second column of my `df` to a "correct value". Points is: Not every possible value of the second column is contemplated on my dictionary. So, if I run the code above, I'll get several null values on the second row, and I wish I could keep these values that does not appear on `mapIds` dictionary.

Is there a way to run the above code but with an exception, that if the value is not on `mapIds` then it keeps the original value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `get` method lets you specify a default:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], mapIds.get(x[1],x[1]), x[2])).toDF()
```